# Cpaturing a window using ximagesrc gives black borders around the image

Tags: gstreamer, xorg

I was trying to capture a single window using `ximagesrc`. Encoding it to png and saving it gives black bordes around the image. This was the command i used.

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc remote=1 num-buffers=1 xid=<windowid> ! videoconvert ! pngenc ! filesink location=screenshot.png
```

and this is the result I've got

[image]

is there any way to remove that borders or to decrease border's alpha?

Comment: Probably by your windows manager for potential shadow drawing. Check if you image viewer interprets alpha correctly.

Comment: oh yeah, that is right. It was a problem with ximagesrc it self and i think the problem is with pngenc(pipeline) method. gimp successfully renders the shadow of the xwd image created by xwd. Thanks